# ListView with ImageButton focusability

Tags: android, android-listview, focus, android-imagebutton

I have a ListView with TextView and ImageButton.

[image: Screenshot]

The ListView have `OnItemClickListener()` and the ImageButton may or may not have `OnClickListener()`.

Below is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<com.bolo.customview.CustomTextViewLight
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/contacts_friends_chat_button"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color_primary"
    android:textSize="@dimen/friend_name"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imagebutton"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/sixtyfour"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/sixtyfour"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sometimes I set the visibility of ImageButton as VISIBLE and sometimes INVISIBLE.

Below is what I want to accomplish.

1. If the ImageButton have onclicklistener then the ImageButton should capture the click on ImageButton and ListView should capture the click on rest of the area. Currently this is running perfectly.
2. If the ImageButton doesn't have onClickListener (ImageButton can be VISIBLE of INVISIBLE doesn't matter) then the ImageButton should never capture the click event. All the click events (On ImageButton and rest of the area) should be captured by ListView. Currently this is not happening. When the ImageButton is VISIBLE then it captures the click event.

How to do this? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can try:

Make the button which you do not want to have a click event : clickable=false.

Or you can put the imageButton visibility as GONE rather than INVISIBLE if you just don't want the click to happen when is invisible.

Comment: I think you haven't read 2nd point clearly. I don't want the ImageButton to capture click event even if its VISIBLE.

Comment: so when did you try clickable = false?